# Finitistic dimension equal to cofinistic dimension for QF-3?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, homological-algebra

Given a finite dimensional algebra A such that the regular module embeds into a projective-injective module (such algebras are called QF-3 algebras and generalise Frobenius algebras).

Define the finitistic dimension findim(A) of A as the supremum of projective dimensions of modules having finite projective  dimension.

> Question:Is the finitistic dimension of $A$ equal to the finitistic dimension of the opposite algebra $A^{op}$?

I see no reason, but some random tests gave no counterexamples to my surprise.

Comment: If you're considering left $A$-modules, then by duality your co-finitistic dimension should coincide with the right finitisitic dimension of $A$.  There are many examples where the left and right finitistic dimension are different, but I don't know yet if any satisfy your additional condition.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a counterexample by accident:

Let A be the following algebra given by quiver and relations (in QPA):

```
    Q:=Quiver( ["v1","v2","v3","v4","v5"], [["v1","v4","a1"],["v2","v1","a2"],["v2","v5","a3"],["v3","v2","a4"],["v4","v2","a5"],["v4","v4","a6"],["v4","v5","a7"],["v5","v3","a8"],["v5","v4","a9"]] );KQ:=PathAlgebra(GF(3),Q);AssignGeneratorVariables(KQ);
rel:=[ a1*a5, a1*a6, a1*a7, a3*a8, a2*a1-a3*a9, a4*a2,a6*a5, a6^2, a5*a3-a6*a7, a7*a8, 
 a8*a4-a9*a5, a9*a7, a5*a2*a1-a7*a9*a6];A:=KQ/rel;Dimension(A);
```

$A$ has dominant dimension 2 and the delooping level of the opposite algebra is also 2 and thus the finitistic projective dimension is 2. But the finitistic injective dimension of $A$ is at least 3, since there exists an indecomposable module with socle $S_5$ and dimension vector [ 0, 1, 1, 0, 1 ] with injective dimension 3. Im not sure whether $A$ has finitistic injective dimension 3 or 4 (the delooping level is 4).